# ebaysdk-python Connection Error

Tags: python, ebay-api, pythonanywhere

I have a django project which is currently being hosted on pythonanywhere that uses the Finding api of the open source project ebaysdk-python. Now on my local machine, the site worked perfectly, however, when I execute the api call I get this error message: `HTTPConnectionPool(host='svcs.ebay.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/search/FindingService/v1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6560105150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`.

Now I have scoured the docs and other related questions, but could not figure out the issue. I have verified that my API keys are correct, and my code to execute the api call is straight from the docs. So that I may be pointed in the correct direction: What is the most likely cause for this error to be raised under these circumstances?

Thank you.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here -- if you're running from a free PythonAnywhere account, it sounds like your code isn't using the proxy settings from the environment.  That's strange because the `requests` library normally picks them up automatically.  Perhaps something else in your code is setting them?

Comment: I do not believe I am setting the proxy settings anywhere else... is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try setting the `proxy_host` and `proxy_port` parameters when you create a Trading object as per [this help page](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/wiki/Trading-API-Class)?  You'll need to set them to `"proxy.server"` and `3128` respectively.

Comment: Wow thank you for this comment @GilesThomas